# Julia: Scope of variables in a nested loop

Tags: loops, scope, julia

I'm trying to change a variable in a for-loop which is in a while-loop. I know that the scope of variables in a for-loop are `local` by default, thus I put a `global` in front of the variable I want to change. This works for `i` but not for `turn`.
When I add `global` in front of `turn` in the for-loop, I get the following error:

> ERROR: LoadError: syntax: `global turn`: turn is a local variable in its enclosing scope

```
i = 0
while(i <= 3)
    global i += 1
    turn = 0
    for j = 1:2
        turn += 1  # if I add a global in front of turn I get an error message
        println("Turn: ", turn)
    end
end
```

The result is:

```
Turn: 1
Turn: 2
Turn: 1
Turn: 2
Turn: 1
Turn: 2
Turn: 1
Turn: 2
```

But what I want is:

```
Turn: 1
Turn: 2
Turn: 3
Turn: 4
Turn: 5
Turn: 6
Turn: 7
Turn: 8
```

How am I able to change `turn` in the nested for-loop?

Comment: if you'd like to use `Turn` for counting the inner `for`-loop, shouldn't it be defined outside the `while`-loop?

Comment: That is correct. I don't exactly understand why, though.

Comment: since ‘turn=0’ is in the while-loop,    you actually reset the LOCAL variable ‘turn’ to 0 every time before running the inner for-loop. Note there is no predefined global variable ‘turn’,  that’s what the error complained about ;)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to get the desired ouptut by moving turn outside the while loop. For the record, I also do not get an error when running your code. What version of Julia are you using?

```
i = 0
turn = 0
while(i <= 3)
    global i += 1
    for j = 1:2
        global turn += 1  
        println("Turn: ", turn)
    end
end
```

Comment: You're right, putting the turn outside the while-loop works. Thank you. I'm using version 1.0. The code above works fine, but adding the `global` in front of the `turn` variable will result in an error.

Comment: @HansBambel It should give you an error because `turn` in your code is a local variable and there is not a global `turn` defined in your code (so you cannot refer to a global `turn`). The problem in your code was `turn` gets zeroed at each `while` iteration, that is why you do not get the result you wanted.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!